# Atomically decrement data member of a union?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, compare-and-swap

I have a struct in a union with uint64_t, providing access to two int32_t. I would like to decrement one of the struct members atomically. I came up with this:

```
class{

public:

void atomicallyDecrement_B(const int32_t decrementByThisValue){
    MyUnion newUnion;
    MyStruct currentStruct = _union._data;

    do{
        const int32_t currentB = currentStruct.b;
        const int32_t currentA = currentStruct.a;
        const int32_t newB = currentB - decrementByThisValue;

        newUnion._data.a = currentA;
        newUnion._data.b = newB;
    }
    while(!std::atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&_union._data, &currentStruct, newUnion._data));
}

private:
    struct MyStruct{
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    union MyUnion{
        MyUnion(){
            _data.a = 0;
            _data.b = 0;
        }

        MyStruct _data;
        uint64_t _atomic;
    } _union;
};
```

but it seems the first argument to `atomic_compare_exchange_weak()` must be an atomic type itself. Is there any way to perform this operation **without** changing the uint64_t data member to be `std::atomic<uint64_t>`?

I am using GCC 5.2

Comment: You can't atomically access a non-atomic data type. If you don't want to make it atomic, you had better guard access with a lock.

Comment: There are non-standard ways to do it -- each compiler/build environment created its own before atomic appeared in the standard.    If this would be of help, specify what compiler you are using and what platform you are running on.

Comment: @DaleWilson compiler-specific is fine, I am using GCC 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC has atomic operations as built-ins.  They are described on [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

The operation you are looking for is

```
type __sync_val_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval, ...)
```

or

```
bool __sync_bool_compare_and_swap (type *ptr, type oldval type newval, ...)
```

These builtins perform an atomic compare and swap. That is, if the current value of *ptr is oldval, then write newval into *ptr.

For Windows users the corresponding capability is

```
LONG __cdecl InterlockedCompareExchange(
  _Inout_ LONG volatile *Destination,
  _In_    LONG          Exchange,
  _In_    LONG          Comparand
);
```

Which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx)

Example using the bool form of the gcc intrinsic:

```
do{
   int oldVal = protectedVal;
   int newVal = someFunction(oldVal);
} while (__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&protectedVal, oldVal, newVal);
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking the GCC intrinsic doesnt copy the unexpected value to the 2nd/3rd argument, if the expected value is not found in the "atomic"?

Comment: It returns the value from *ptr before the swap.   You can compare it to oldval to see if the swap worked.  There is another method that returns a bool to indicated whether the swap happened.  It does not give you the "before" value.  I edited my answer to provide sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to do this. You can either use GCC atomic builtins found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html or you can use atomic functions provided by your OS. The third option is to use atomic assembly instructions.